# Return snd element of specific tuple in list of tuples Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, element

I am trying to return the second element of a tuple that has the same first element as the char.

If there isn't a tuple with same char as it's first element then I want to return 0

There can only be 0 or 1 tuples with the same char as the char given, hence taking the head of the [Int] returned by the list comprehension.

this is the code I wrote, the error is when I try to check whether a tuple (c,*) is in the list of tuples with 'elem (c,*) m'

```
type Mem = [(Name,Int)]

getVal :: Char -> Mem -> Int
getVal c m
        | elem (c,_) m = head [snd n | n <- m, fst n == c]
        | otherwise = 0
```

A fix for that problem, or a suggestion of a better way to do this would be recieved gratefully!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elem (c,_)` is not a valid haskell expression, because `_` can only be used in a pattern (and not in a value). You almost have the solution with `head [snd n | n <- m, fst n == c]`. You should first evaluate it, and check what is inside. It will be simpler and safer.

I would use something like

```
getVal :: Char -> Mem -> Int
getVal c m = case [snd n | n <- m, fst n == c] of
    [] -> 0
    x:_ -> x
```

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple, if you know the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html) well.

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

getVal :: Char -> Mem -> Int
getVal c = fromMaybe 0 . lookup c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`:

```
import Data.List

getVal :: Char -> Mem -> Int
getVal c = maybe 0 snd . find ((==)c) . fst)
```

Comment: `find (c==)` instead is a bit cleaner